# No matching function for call to 'std::vector<int>::insert' when using a macro

Tags: c++, macros

I wrote a code which performs some operation on vectors, in which I have defined a macro:

```
#define all(c) ((c).begin(),(c).end())
```

...and used that macro for vector insertion using `v2.insert(1, all(v1))`.

This means that I want to insert all elements from vector `v1` at the second position in vector `v2`. But, I am getting the following error on the line with the `insert` function call:

> no matching function for call to 'std::vector::insert...

The code is as follows:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<vector>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define all(c) ((c).begin(),(c).end())
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int data[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    vector<int> v1(data+1,data+5);
    vector<int> v2(2,1);

    v2.insert(1,all(v1));

    printf("\n Before the for loop");
    for(vector<int> v2::iterator it=v2.begin();it!=v2.end();it++)
    {
        printf("\t %d \t ",*it++);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First: macros, *especially* used that way is bad. Don't do that. Second, I think you macro don't work because of the extra parenthesis around the begin and end. In fact, `(begin, end)` invoke the comma operator, which drops `begin`

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot I tried by removing the extra parentheses. Still , it wouldnt work.

Comment: *"Still , it wouldnt work"* - Reading the documentation of [`std::vector::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) would help. You are trying to call an overload that doesn't exist. The competitive programming macro nonsense is just masking that.

Answer (score 7):

Because of the macro, you have `v2.insert(1,((v1).begin(),(v1).end()))` with the inner `((v1).begin(),(v1).end())` using [the built-in comma operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator) instead of the argument separator. Which means what you're really doing is `v2.insert(1,((v1).end()))`

I suggest you don't use macros to "shorten" things like that. Besides creating problems like you have, it also tend to make code *harder* to read, understand and maintain.

Comment: Can you suggest me any alternatives if not to use macros for this operation which I want to perform?

Comment: @H.patel Just use `v1.begin()` and `v1.end()` like everybody else are doing?

Comment: @H.patel: or use range library ([range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3)) or write your own helper functions, something like: `template <typename T>void (std::vector<T>& v, const std::vector<T>& v2);`